# Regex, end of line or other character than "-"

Tags: regex, oracle

I've made a Regex here to show my problem:
https://regex101.com/r/zV2oL1/1

The first two lines are ok, but when the line has an "-" near the end it should not match, as in this case: the third line.

```
WILD CARROT - POTATOE 1 PIE 2
WILD CARROT - POTATOE 1 PIE 2 OK
WILD CARROT - POTATOE 1 PIE 2 - NOT OK
```

I don't understand why ending my regex with:

```
($|[^-])
```

doesn't work.

**Update** to be clear, only the first two lines should match

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(subject, '.*?POTATOE.*?\d.*?PIE.*?\d', 'im') THEN
    -- Successful match
ELSE
    -- Match attempt failed
END IF;
```

---

EXPLANATION:

```
.*?POTATOE.*?\d.*?PIE.*?\d

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks

Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “POTATOE” literally (case insensitive) «POTATOE»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “PIE” literally (case insensitive) «PIE»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is checking for an end-of-line `$` OR a character that's not `-` anywhere in the string (which matches because the bad string has an end-of-line and a character that's not `-`). To match strings without a `-` in them anywhere, use this:
`^[^-]*$`
To match strings without the character `-` at the end of the line, use this:
`[^-]$`
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
.*POTATOE.*?\d.*?PIE.*?\d[^\-]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^.*POTATOE.*?\d.*?PIE \d[^-]*$
```

With "m" and "g" modifiers together. Resulting in:

```
/^.*POTATOE.*?\d.*?PIE \d[^-]*$/mg
```